# Using grep output as pattern for another grep

Tags: bash, grep

I have three files, **a**, **b**, and **c**. **c** has has a list of codes. **b** has two columns: a column of codes and their corresponding `test` name. The last file, **a**, has a list of names *which contain* (as substrings) all test names. Examples:

> **c**:
>
> ```
> codeb
> coded
> codea
> codec
> codee
> codef
> codee
> codeg
> codeh
> ```
>
> **b**:
>
> ```
> codea   testa
> codeb   testb
> codec   testc
> coded   testa
> codee   testa
> codef   testb
> codeg   testc
> codeh   testa
> ```
>
> **a**:
>
> ```
> testa1234
> testb21345
> 14231testcAr
> ```

I want to output the corresponding name in **a** file for each code in **c**. For example, `codeb` should output `testb21345`. I haven't been able to make it work. I think this has to do with grep not understanding the pattern. This is the loop I have written as MVE:

```
diractual=$PWD

while read line; do

        ca=$(grep $line $diractual/b | cut -f 2)  
        ca_complete=$(grep $ca $diractual/a)
        echo "This is ca:"
        echo "$ca"
        echo "This is ca_complete:"
        echo "$ca_complete"
done <$diractual/c
```

The two `echo`s *should output*, for example for `codeb` (the first line in **c**):

```
        This is ca:
        testb
        This is ca_complete:
        testb21345
```

But it outputs (for every line):

```
        This is ca:
        testb
        This is ca_complete:

        #(Empty line)
```

So the first `grep` is finding the correct `test` and it is storing it in variable `ca` but the second one is not finding this pattern in **a**.

Comment: When setting `ca_complete` you're greping from `c` again, don't you mean to get it from `a`?

Comment: @EricRenouf Correct, typo.

Comment: @anubhava Ahm, right...?

Comment: Does your file `b` have carriage returns at the end of it perhaps?

Comment: @EricRenouf I have created all the files using nano, how can I check if I have carriage returns?

Comment: You could try running `file` on it and see if it says that it has `CRLF line terminators`

Comment: `file b` outputs b: ASCII text

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139078/discussion-between-eric-renouf-and-d1x).

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using bash and grep, it would be simpler and likely faster to use a single awk invocation to produce the desired output. For example, with GNU awk for thr `ARGIND` variable, you can write:

```
$ gawk 'ARGIND==1{a[$1]=$2}ARGIND==2{b[$1]}ARGIND==3{for(i in b) if ($0 ~ a[i]) print i, $0}' b c a
codeh testa1234
codea testa1234
coded testa1234
codee testa1234
codef testb21345
codeb testb21345
codeg 14231testcAr
codec 14231testcAr
```

In a more readable format it would be:

```
gawk ' ARGIND == 1 { a[$1] = $2 } 
       ARGIND == 2 { b[$1] }
       ARGIND == 3 {
           for (i in b) 
               if ($0 ~ a[i])
                   print i, $0
       }' b c a
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right

```
filea="a"
fileb="b"
filec="c"
while read -r code
do
        printf "%s: %s\n" "$code" "$(grep "$(grep -oP "^$code\s+\K.*" "$fileb")" "$filea")"
done < "$filec"
```

prints

```
codeb: testb21345
coded: testa1234
codea: testa1234
codec: 14231testcAr
codee: testa1234
codef: testb21345
codee: testa1234
codeg: 14231testcAr
codeh: testa1234
```

or divided into alone steps

```
while read -r code
do
        tst=$(grep -oP "^$code\s+\K.*" "$fileb")
        res=$(grep "$tst" "$filea")
        printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n" "$code" "$tst"  "$res"
done < "$filec"
```

prints

```
codeb   testb   testb21345
coded   testa   testa1234
codea   testa   testa1234
codec   testc   14231testcAr
codee   testa   testa1234
codef   testb   testb21345
codee   testa   testa1234
codeg   testc   14231testcAr
codeh   testa   testa1234
```